# Inversion + continuous tense

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, subject-verb-inversion

How can I write the inverted sentence included continuous tense?

For example,
(A) On the hill were training many people.
(B) On the hill were many people training.

Can I write the sentence both way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of the inverted variations make it entirely clear if what's being described is people who are *conducting* training or people who are *being* trained.

For an inverted sentence that clarifies the situation, the following would be better:

> On the hill were many people **in** training.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to say either: Many people were training on the hill. Or, On the hill, many people were training. "On the hill were training many people" is just awkward, because one wonders *who* is training "many people."